# Removing line spacing between paragraphs in a Word Document in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm filling a table cell line by line with a richTextBox's content with this code :

```
int length = richTextBoxes[0].Lines.Length;
for (int index = 1; index < length; index++) {
    table.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text += richTextBoxes[0].Lines[index].ToString();
}
```

But it automatically passes a weird line before pasting the text, and there is this huge spacing between paragraphs between each lines and I wonder if it's possible to remove it.

Thank you

Comment: As I re-read this it occurred to me that the problem you're seeing may be due to the *style* applied to the table. If that's the case, then it would be more efficient (and correct from the Word POV) to apply the correct style to the table/cells than to apply the formatting directly. (Have also added this to my "Answer")

Comment: Your last answer was good enough for me but this might help others! So thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the line spacing of the paragraphs in a text cell:

```
table.Cell(3,2).Range.Paragraphs.LineSpacing
```

If this does not have the desired effect you should make sure that line spacing is the problem and not some character code that Word isn't dealing with the way you expect. *Type* lines in the table cell, without pressing Enter and see if they exhibit the same behavior as you're seeing with your code. If not, then your code is importing something you'll need to "cut off"...

The problem you're seeing may be due to the *style* applied to the table. If that's the case, then it would be more efficient (and correct from the Word POV) to apply the correct style to the table/cells than to apply the formatting directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` assembly?

How about setting the property `LineSpacing` of `Paragraph` interface? It is a float type.

It can be set after `LineSpacingRule` property is set to one of the following values: `wdLineSpaceAtLeast`, `wdLineSpaceExactly` or `wdLineSpaceMultiple`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, i'm using Interop.Word. Thanks a lot Alex, but document.Paragraphs.LineSpacing is for the whole document, isn't it? Is there a solution only for a specific table cell?

Comment: @UnderPaidIntern Can't you get an instance of a particular paragraph? Just like in Word itself, you can set line spacing for a given paragraph. You should be able to do the same in code. Btw cool nickname